# Determinant of direction cosines of orthogonal vectors.

Tags: vectors, determinant, 3d

Consider three orthogonal vectors in space with direction cosines $l(r), m(r), n(r)$. $(r=1,2,3) $

Show that the determinant of these direction cosines (taken in order) is a constant.

I am not able to find the constant. I worked out the final determinant but am not able to solve it. Need help... thanks in advance!!

Here is the determinant:
\begin{vmatrix}
 l1 & m1 & n1 \\
 l2 & m2 & n2 \\
 l3 & m3 & n3 \\
\end{vmatrix}

Comment: What do you mean by "fixed value"? If the vectors are fixed, then the determinant is fixed, isn't it?

Comment: It's a constant independent of the orientation of the three orthogonal vectors with respect to the fixed coordinate axes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Call $u_r$ the vectors, then the determinant is simply

$$
\Delta = u_1\cdot (u_2 \times u_3) \tag{1}
$$

Since the vectors are orthogonal then $u_2 \times u_3 = \alpha u_1$, with $\alpha$ a constant,

$$
\alpha |u_1| = |u_2\times u_3| = |u_2| |u_3| \sin \theta_{23} = \pm|u_2| |u_3|
$$

where $\theta_{23}$ is the angle formed by the vectors $u_2$ and $u_3$, which can be either $\pi/2$ or $-\pi/2$. Therefore

$$
\alpha = \pm\frac{|u_2||u_3|}{|u_1|} \tag{2}
$$

Evaluating (2) in (1) we then get

$$
\Delta = u_1 \cdot (\alpha u_1) = \alpha |u_1|^2 = \pm|u_1||u_2| |u_3|
$$

That is, the determinant depends only on the lengths of the vectors and, therefore, is independent of the direction cosines

Comment: Alright thanks!! But what would be the value of the determinant I have mentioned in the question?

Comment: @SirXYZ The determinant is exactly $\Delta$ in Eq. (1)

Comment: Ok... my book says that the constant is just the no. 2. I think it must be a misprint...thanks again!!

Comment: If the vectors are orthonormal then $\Delta = \pm 1$